# hierarchical_mutex: are spurious exceptions possible?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, deadlock

In his book, *C++ Concurrency in Action*, A. Williams introduces the concept of a lock hierarchy as a deadlock-avoidance mechanism. Below, I report a stripped down version of a `HierarchicalMutex` implementation (taken from the book):

```
class HierarchicalMutex {
   private:
    std::mutex Mutex_;
    unsigned const Level_;
    unsigned PrevLevel_{0};
    static thread_local unsigned current_level;

   public:
    explicit HierarchicalMutex(unsigned level) : Level_{level} {}

    void lock() {
        if (current_level <= this->Level_) { // (1)
            // I can only lock a mutex with a lower level than the currently
            // locked one.
            throw std::logic_error("lock: Out of order");
        }

        this->Mutex_.lock();
        this->PrevLevel_ = std::exchange(current_level, this->Level_);
    }

    // try_lock implemented accordingly [...]

    void unlock() {
        if (current_level != this->Level_)
            throw std::logic_error("unlock: Out of order");

        current_level = this->PrevLevel_;
        this->Mutex_.unlock();
    }
};

// current_level initialized to UINT_MAX so that, in the beginning, any
// HierarchicalMutex may be locked.
thread_local unsigned HierarchicalMutex::current_level{
    std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()};
```

Les's imagine threads *A* and *B* competing to lock an instance of `HierarchicalMutex`, as shown in the following code:

```
int main() {
    HierarchicalMutex mutex{1};

    std::thread threadA{[&mutex] { std::scoped_lock sl{mutex}; }};
    std::thread threadB{[&mutex] { std::scoped_lock sl{mutex}; }};

    threadB.join();
    threadA.join();
}
```

Say that thread *A*:

- Calls `mutex.lock()`;
- Successfully evaluates check `(1)` to `false`;
- Locks `HierarchicalMutex::Mutex_`;
- Updates `HierarchicalMutex::current_level` and sets it to `1`.

At this point, thread *B*:

- Calls `mutex.lock()`;
- Evaluates check `(1)` to `true`.

This means that thread *B* will throw; but I'd expect it to wait until thread *A* unlocks `mutex`.

My questions are:

1. Is the execution flow I pictured even possible?
2. If so, is it correct for thread *B* to throw or should it wait for thread *A* to unlock `mutex` (as I'd expect)?
3. If my expectation is correct, how should `HierarchicalMutex` be implemented in order for thread *B* to wait instead of throwing? Is it enough to replace `<=` in check `(1)` with `<`?

Comment: In all my 30 years of concurrent programming in C++, I've never seen (or needed) such a complicated synchronization primitive. What problem does it try to solve? (To me it looks like a solution looking for a problem)

Comment: @PepijnKramer It's a way to enforce that several mutex are always locked and unlocked in the same order. If that's not the case, you'll get an exception and go fix the code that violated the lock ordering. In my example, I only use one mutex as it's enough to explain what my question is about. However, you'd tipically have several mutexes; each with its own level.

Comment: Okay I see what it is supposed to do now. Still can't think of any place where I would have needed one. It kind of seems to imply that mutexes can be over the length of multiple function calls in which other locks can happen. Hard to tell exactly why but something is bothering me about that. I usually desing in such a way that locks are short and never lock longer then one scope. Could be this looks strange because I never needed something like this ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At this point, thread B:
>
> Calls mutex.lock();
>
> Evaluates check (1) to true.

No it won't. `current_level` is declared as a `thread_local` object. If you are unfamiliar with what that means, see your C++ textbook for a more complete discussion, but it boils down that `current_level` is a separate, discrete object in each execution thread. In both execution threads it's 0, and `check (1)` evaluates to `false`.